# difference between find . -name '*.xyz' (dot space hyphen) and find . .name '*.xyz' (dot space dot)

Tags: linux

Our on-call staffer accidentally deleted files in our production server.

I instructed him to issue a find command to delete stray files like so (notice `find dot space hyphen`)

```
find . -name '*.xyz' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

but as he copied/pasted the command from my email to his shell session, the hyphen was changed to a dot (I witnessed it. He showed it to me) and the following command was executed (notice `find dot space dot`)

```
find . .name '*.xyz' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

This deleted files locally and recursively. Including symbolic links. Thankfully, we were able to recover everything from a backup.

The man page on my server only the `-name` flag. Nothing about `.name`. Why did `find` ignore the file extension I specified?

We're on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga), running KSH 93.

Comment: There's nothing special about `.`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you understand why `program A B C` is interpreted different than `program A -B C` then you will understand what happened.

As far as `find` is concerned, you never specified an extension because you never used the `-name` flag.  `.name` is interpreted as a path to search just like `.`.  `find` allows you to [specify multiple paths](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) like that.  You told `find` to search in files and directories named `.`, files and directories named `.name`, and files and directories named `'*.xyz'` and delete everything there.

Answer (score 3):

In practice find searched for all files starting from `.` , `.name`, and `'.xyz'` , interpreting those as paths, probably the last two gave error messages like

```
find: `.name': No such file or directory
find: `*.xyz': No such file or directory
```

and then executed the rm command on those.